# extract the location coordinates of a web page

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I want to extract the coordinates of each house for sale on a web page, however I can not get it.
The page is the following:

```
https://www.fincaraiz.com.co/casa-en-venta/cali/valle_del_lili-det-4710841.aspx#pnlMap



 require(rvest)

    pageurl <- "https://www.fincaraiz.com.co/casa-en-venta/cali/valle_del_lili-det-4710841.aspx"

    htmlpage <- read_html(pageurl)



    htmlpage %>%
      html_nodes(
##I can't think of how to continue
```

I hope to get the coordinates of the house, through HTML.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Do check the source code of the page, `DivGoogleMaps` is empty. There is a script containing `var sfAdvert` with all the information (including coordinates) and two variables called `MapFR.latitude` and `MapFR.longitude`. Try grabbing those.

Comment: Also check the source of your code ... I don't think `"//*[@id="DivGoogleMaps"]"` is a valid string, for me it complains `Error: unexpected symbol in ""//*[@id="DivGoogleMaps"`. (Too many double quotes.) Can you get your code to execute without that error? If not, share your actual code. Perhaps you can try replacing it (and the next string, too) with `'//*[@id="DivGoogleMaps"]'` (note the single-quotes on the outside). (I don't know, is `... %>% [str_detect(...)]` legit with the square brackets?)

Comment: I think the code does not work, I am very new to this and I can't think of another way to get the strings. How else do you suggest getting it?

I just want to get the strings of the house that is stuck on the map.

before hand thank you friends

Comment: link: https://www.fincaraiz.com.co/casa-en-venta/cali/valle_del_lili-det-4710841.aspx#pnlMap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in comments there is a javascript dictionary in one of the scripts tags you can regex out and parse with json parser to get those values. I go for the larger object in case you want other info about the listing.

```
library(rvest)
library(stringr)
library(magrittr)
library(jsonlite)

r <- read_html('https://www.fincaraiz.com.co/casa-en-venta/cali/valle_del_lili-det-4710841.aspx#pnlMap') %>%
  html_node('body') %>%
  html_text() %>%
  toString()
data <- str_match_all(r,'var sfAdvert = (.*?);')
data <- data.frame(jsonlite::fromJSON(data[[1]][,2]))

print(data$Latitude)
print(data$Longitude)
```

Comment: I have an error when the url of the page changes, what is this due to?.
this is the new url:https://www.fincaraiz.com.co/trece-lunas/cali/proyecto-nuevo-det-4745905.aspx

Comment: the code you provide works, but I have an error changing the URL of the page to https://www.fincaraiz.com.co/trece-lunas/cali/proyecto-nuevo-det-4745905.aspx

Comment: have you inspected the html of the new page to see if there is a var sfAdvert?

Comment: I do not know how to do it.  could you help me?

Comment: F12 to open dev tools on the webpage (e.g. with Chrome). Select _elements_ tab. Click on anything in elements tab > press Ctrl + F > enter _var sfAdvert_ in the search box > hit enter > see if any results.

Comment: this is the error i get:  Error: parse error: premature EOF
                                       {"AdvertId" : "4745905", "Adver
                     (right here) ------^

Comment: If there are results.

Comment: What could be the problem?

Comment: I will have to have a look at this tomorrow as I am currently working on something else. Please remind me tomorrow in case I forget.

Comment: I completely forgot. Sorry. Will look tomorrow.

Comment: Please could you review it today, I have to solve this problem today. I would greatly appreciate it

Comment: swop regex line to:  data <- str_match_all(r,'var sfAdvert = (.*);')  then at end ..... data$Latitude  etc....

Comment: You're the best

Comment: No worries. Glad it helped.